# What is HTTP 400 Bad Request in Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

What is Http 400 Bad Request and what causes it to happen?

What is method I can use to know which `key` in `request.form[key]` that cause bad request and how can I prevent it?

**Updated**

As Gerand mentioned in his comment:

> This error happens when you are requesting a file through http which
> doesn't exist [....]

To make it clearer, here my sample code that cause `Bad Request`:

**hello.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import *
import re

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checkName():

    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/hello',methods=['GET','POST'])
def printName():
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        bad_key = request.form['bad_key'] # this key is not exist
        
        return "Hello, ",username

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**hello.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='/hello' method='POST' name="frm_submit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

From code above, the browser return `Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` without giving clue that which key that cause this error.

Therefore, which method I can use to know which `key` that cause this error, and how can I prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do? what libraries are you using...
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @KaustubhKallianpur, I am trying to know what cause the `Error 400 Bad Request` in python? how can I know the cause and prevent that? thanks.

Comment: This error happens when you are requesting a file through http which doesn't exist. It has nothing to do with python.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840303/urllib2-http-error-400-bad-request) maybe of some help. If there is something else, we would need some code input.

Comment: @Gerard Isn't that "404 - Not found"? 400 refers to a corrupt request

Comment: @lausek totally right, I kind of brainfarted. Usually happens to me

Comment: @KaustubhKallianpur, please refer to my updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Flask uses the [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) library's `MultiDict` data structure to hold POST data.

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/66215c0bc03d00c3b80f2d84071d575b9b893ce6/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L419) of `MultiDict.__getitem__`, you can see that if a key is not found, it will raise `BadRequestKeyError` with the name of the key as an argument.  So you can inspect the exception's `args` attribute to get the name of the bad key:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequestKeyError

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        try:
            bad_key = request.form['bad_key']
        except BadRequestKeyError as ex: 
            return 'Unknown key: "{}"'.format(ex.args[0]), 500
```

Note that while `BadRequestKeyError`s *string representation* is

> 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

the status of the response is actually

> 500 Internal Server Error

The keys of `request.form` correspond to the `name` attributes of the `input` tags in the form(s) in the HTML page being POSTed.  Thus a `BadRequestKeyError` will often be caused by a mismatch between the `name` attributes in the HTML and the names expected by `request.form['some_name']` in the route.