# Why BadrequestKeyError is showing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am making a small project - Reminider System. I have a form which accepts values from users and inserts into the database table. The problem is occurring while fetching a value from a textbox. Below is my code and also I am giving what error am getting.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="unique" value="{{session.UID}}" disabled="true">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

This is my template

```py
@app.route('/home/set_reminder',methods=['POST'])
@is_logged_in
def set_reminder():
    if request.method=='POST' and form.validate():
        uid = request.form['unique']
```

I am getting the error in this line `uid = request.form['unique']`. Not getting why it cannot fetch the value.

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'unique'
```

And this is the error which am getting.
Please help me out.

Comment: Why have you used disabled? The field is hidden anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, the `uid` input is *disabled*, so the browser will not send `uid` in a POST request's body.  This causes the error when you try to access `request.form.uid` - it doesn't exist.

You could use *readonly* rather than *disabled* if the value must be returned by the browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54169274/5320906) for a little more information on `BadRequestKeyError`.