# Issue with my python/flask application: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm making a web application that lets users create chatrooms.

This function displays the chatroom messages

```
@app.route('/enter/<room>')
def enter_chat_room(room):
    r = Room.query.filter_by(name=room).first()
    return render_template('chatRoom.html', room=r)
```

This function adds a new message. message.content returns a string with the actual contents of the message object

```
@app.route('/message/<room>', methods=['POST'])
def post_message(room):
    r = Room.query.filter_by(name=room).first()
    message = Message(content=request.form['message'], room_id=r.id)
    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()
    return json.dumps(message.content)
```

This is chatRoom.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<h1>{{ room.name }}</h1>
<div class="page">
    <ul class="messages" id="list">
        {% for m in room.messages %}
            <li>{{ m.content }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('post_message', room=room.name) }}">
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
    <div class="actions"><input type="button" value="Enter" id="theButton"></div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the script.js file

```
function setup(){
    document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", sendit);
}

function sendit(){
    const message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    fetch("/message/<room>", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({message: "contents"})
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.json())
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        updateMessages(result);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("Error posting your message!");
    });
}

function updateMessages(result){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result));
    list.appendChild(li);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

The issue I'm getting is that every time I try to post a message I get an error message in the console that says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)" and one that says "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" means your request get a html file as response. In bumped into this when having a catch all route which would return  a 404 page.

Comment: @Mark But, why would it get an html file as a response?

Comment: Probably the POSTed form data  is wrong - [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54169274/5320906)